# Como paginar via querystring sem recarregar a página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu faço a listagem dos produtos via uma querystring como no exemplo: "{meusite?pg=1}"

Eu vi que no site das americanas e walmart eles fazem uma paginação semelhante à minha, mas sem recarregar o resto da página.

Como eu faço para implementar isto no meu site ?

Comment: Você terá que usar ajax a cada requisição de outra página, vou deixar uma lista com demonstrações para você seguir. http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/best-ajax-jquery-pagination-plugin-tutorial-with-example-demo/

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que fazer uma requisição via ajax para solicitar para o web service apenas o conteúdo necessário e em tempo de execução plotar os dados recebidos. Formas de implementação existem várias e tudo depende do resultado que se deseja.

Ajax com jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sua resposta não responde a pergunta. Edite sua resposta colocando um exemplo, explicando como funciona. Links podem expirar com o tempo.

Comment: Realmente não responde

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, não tenho certeza da pergunta. Sua duvida é quanto ao método de paginação sem recarregar a página (neste caso quanto ao uso do ajax que o amigo Yuri lhe respondeu) ou previnir que o browser recarregue a pagina quando trocar o parametro da url (quando trocar de meusite?p=1 para meusite?p=2)? Se este for o caso, sugiro o uso de ancora "#" e eventos javascript (usando o ajax do amigo Yuri para a troca do conteúdo). 
Pesquisando algo simples pra vc achei: 
http://joakim.beng.se/blog/posts/a-javascript-router-in-20-lines.html   Ainda, para um entendimento melhor,  pesquise sobre rotas javascript. É usado em aplicações SPA - Single Page Application